# Issue with Safari elastic scroll and fixed position elements that have a lower z-index

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a div `.main-container` and behind it are 2 divs with lower z-index's one on the left `.left-drawer` of the page one on the right `.right-drawer`.

Both are drawers, when triggered the `.main-container` moves to the left or to the right to reveal each drawer.

This all works fine, my issue is that due to Safari's elastic scroll when you scroll to the top or bottom of the page the **fixed divs** with **lower z-index's** are visible. This happens on both Desktop and Mobile.

Is there a way to stop this? Here's a simplified version:

HTML:

```
<div class="drawer left-drawer">
  Left Drawer
</div>

<div class="drawer right-drawer">
  Right Drawer
</div>

<div class="main-container">
  Main Content
  <a href="#" class="open-left-drawer">Left</a>
  <a href="#" class="open-right-drawer">Right</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.drawer {
position: fixed;
display: block;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.left-drawer {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.right-drawer {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.main-container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 99;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```